# If not DeclareOption

Tags: conditionals, package-options

I have some documents using a same custom package. That "header" package loads by default the package `fullpage`. But I would like to write a new LaTeX document, using the same header, but without loading `fullpage`, and I don't want to change old files.

Is there a way to add an "if false" condition about options? I mean. I have currently:

```
\DeclareOption{fullpage}{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
}
```

But that implies to change all of my old documents to add the fullpage option to my package. I want however to make something like:

```
if-not-nofullpage {%
  \usepackage{fullpage}
}
```

And in my new document:

```
\usepackage[nofullpage]{my-header}
```

Or perhaps a way to "unload" a previously loaded package:

```
\usepackage{fullpage} % inconditionally

\DeclareOption{nofullpage} {%
    unload-or-revert-the-fullpage-inclusion
}
```

How can I do that? (if plain TeX macros are used in your answers, please, with little explanations).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to load `fullpage` after `\ProcessOptions`, first of all.

Here's the scheme:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\newif\ifmypackage@fullpage
\DeclareOption{fullpage}{\mypackage@fullpagetrue}
\DeclareOption{nofullpage}{\mypackage@fullpagefalse}

\ExecuteOptions{fullpage} % default is fullpage

\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifmypackage@fullpage
  \RequirePackage{fullpage}
\fi
```

Then a document calling either

```
\usepackage{myclass}
```

or

```
\usepackage[fullpage]{myclass}
```

will load `fullpage`; a document calling

```
\usepackage[nofullpage]{myclass}
```

won't.

Thus you won't have to change your old document, but new ones will be able to avoid loading of `fullpage`.

Comment: Thanks egreg. What is the difference between \RequirePackage and \usepackage? I've read they are synonyms, but, really synonyms? Why two commands with same meaning?

Comment: @Peregring-lk In packages or classes `\RequirePackage` should be used. It's mostly a tradition, but having two separate command names can be used by the LaTeX developers for adding functionality to one of the commands without changing the meaning of the other.

Comment: Your solution works perfect. Elegant, direct and short. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 - I took the liberty of taking your example and [modifying](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279142/430) it to use [kvoptions](http://ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [kvoptions](http://ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions):

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{fullpage}       % automatically creates \ifmypackage@fullpage
\DeclareComplementaryOption{nofullpage}{fullpage}  % automatically inverses the former
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*{}

\ifmypackage@fullpage
  \RequirePackage{fullpage}
\fi
```

(based on [egreg's example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135255/430)

See also the question on [Mutually exclusive options in packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21171/430)

Comment: Thanks for linking to "Mutually exclusive..." question. It worked like a charm there, the answer provided by "Martin Scharrer"!