# \ExecuteOptions error \CurrentOption \@nil

Tags: package-options

I try to follow this scheme :

[If not DeclareOption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135248/if-not-declareoption)

but have an error of this type :

[I get an error when using `\ExecuteOptions` together with `\usepackage{geometry}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/i-get-an-error-when-using-executeoptions-together-with-usepackagegeometry)

but I don't understand how to fix it.

Here is my MWE :

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[marginparsep=3pt, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\newif\ifMyFancy

\DeclareOption{fancy}{\MyFancytrue}
\DeclareOption{nofancy}{\MyFancyfalse}

\ExecuteOptions{fancy}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifMyFancy
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\fi
```

and

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bob}

\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{6}}
\fancyhead[R]{27 mai 2015}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{Devoir commun}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\begin{document}
essai
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the first snippet supposed to be `bob.sty`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems very similar to [SF298 package giving undefined control sequence error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148153/sf298-package-giving-undefined-control-sequence-error) and seems due to the same problem: both `geometry` and `totpages` do some tricks with `\ExecuteOptions` which end up with `\CurrentOption` defined as `\@nil`.

As soon as you load any other package after `geometry` this problem vanishes, but it's clearly a bug.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\show\CurrentOption
```

which shows, on the terminal,

```
> \CurrentOption=macro:
->\@nil .
```

Workaround: add `\def\CurrentOption{}` after loading `geometry` or move the call to `geometry` before calling `fontenc`.