# Passing an if-else option to a custom sty file

Tags: packages, optional-arguments, package-options

I have a custom `.sty` file loading needed packages and defining some commands and environments. Is there an easy way to either:

- define an if-else option
- define option's default value

I am using the `babel` package and want to specify it's options:

```
\usepackage[english, czech]{babel}
```

But sometimes, I need the opposite:

```
\usepackage[czech, english]{babel}
```

Is there a way to use it like this?

```
\usepackage{myPackage} % loads "english, czech"
\usepackage[en]{myPackage} % loads "czech, english"
```

Comment: You need a bool-option. More specifications will be possible if you provide a small MWE with your used keyval package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2014/01/05 ...]
...
\newif\if@mylang\@mylangfalse
\DeclareOption{en}{\@mylangtrue}
...
\DeclareOption*{\OptionNotUsed}
\ProcessOptions\relax
...
\if@mylang 
  \RequirePackage[english,czech]{babel}
\else
  \RequirePackage[czech,english]{babel}%% the default
\fi
...
```

If you need the default the other way round then change the definition.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple way of doing it. The following code is a minimalist `.sty` file called `yourpackagename`. It defines a switch `\ifyourpkgprefix@enoption` and declares an option called `en` which, if passed to your package, sets the switch to true. After the option(s) have been processed, the `babel` package is loaded with options `english` and `czech` in the desired order, on the basis of the switch's value.

Of course, you should choose different package name, prefix, description, etc.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{yourpackagename}[2014/01/05 v0.1 yourpackagedescription]

% switch for 'en' option
\newif\ifyourpkgprefix@enoption\yourpkgprefix@enoptionfalse

\DeclareOption{en}{\yourpkgprefix@enoptiontrue}
\DeclareOption*{\OptionNotUsed} % discard any undeclared option

\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifyourpkgprefix@enoption
    \RequirePackage[czech, english]{babel}
\else
    \RequirePackage[english, czech]{babel}  
\fi

\endinput
```

Here is a MWE using that package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{yourpackagename}                   % comment one of those two lines
\usepackage[en]{yourpackagename}

\begin{document}

% --- sanity check ---
The \texttt{babel} options were loaded in the following order:
\makeatletter
\ifyourpkgprefix@enoption%
    \texttt{czech, english} (option~\texttt{en} was passed).
\else%
    \texttt{english, czech} (option~\texttt{en} was NOT passed).
\fi
\makeatother
% --------------------

foobar

\end{document}
```

Useful resources:

- http://latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf
- [Loading a package conditionally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/loading-a-package-conditionally)
- [Mutually exclusive options in packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21171/mutually-exclusive-options-in-packages)